# Can't pass a char array (file name) to fopen(file,r)

Tags: c, file, path, fopen

I want users to enter their own file name they want into the program, then the program opens it. I don't know why it doesn't work, please help. It just works if I define the path directly on the code.

**This works.**

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Test\\text.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    index = 0;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("ok");
    }
    fclose(file);
} else {
    printf("Can't open file");
}
```

**This doesn't work.**

```
char inputFile[100];

printf("Enter file name: ");
scanf("%s", inputFile);

FILE *file;
file = fopen(inputFile, "r");
if (file) {
    index = 0;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("ok");
    }
    fclose(file);
} else {
    printf("Can't open file");
}
```

Comment: Post exact input used.  "it doesn't work" is vague - provide more detail.  Even better, add a [mcve].

Comment: I would add a `printf("{%s}\n", inputFile);` to the code, and make sure the file name is correct.

Comment: Code works fine here. But a few things; 1) Your code is missing some declarations (index, c). 2) You need to post what kind of errors you're getting! 3) You didn't say what your input is!

Comment: @chux It doesn't show any error. Just do nothing.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, you are right, I added to check and it shows that scanf didn't handle the space in the path.

Comment: @LouisTran Ahh yes, that's true, scanf will stop at the first space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading in from code, you need to escape your "\", but scanf isn't as smart. You just need to enter the text as is!

> C:\Users\Test\text.txt

Also, note that scanf ("%s", inputFile) won't handle spaces in the file name path, so "My Documents" won't work.

Comment: Thanks. scanf doesn't handle spaces. It caused the issue.

Comment: @LouisTran `scanf()` can "handle" spaces, it is just that `scanf("%s", inputFile)` does not "handle" them as you want.

Comment: @chux That's correct, I updated the answer to reflect that